# How to create a website custom scrollbar for iPhone?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

My website's scrollbar design is working fine in chrome browser but not working on iPhone, how can I fix this?

Made custom overlay-scrollbar with native scrolling mechanism for web application but not working on iPhone

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that you'll need a custom scrollbar on iPhone, since nobody really uses scrollbars on mobile devices anyway. Scrolling with your fingers anywhere on the screen is just more convenient.

I also found this [Apple Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670065), where they say that custom scrollbar support was canceled with IOS 14, because nobody was actually using it.

You could, of course, do it the (very) hard way, by making a div for the scrollbar, and a div for the scroll-button, fixing it to the side, and kind of reverse engineering the regular Windows scrollbar using JavaScript, but I wouldn't recommend it for user experience reasons.

Hope this helps.
Happy coding!